# Scala Graph DFS postorder time

Tags: scala, graph, depth-first-search, postorder

I have been successful retrieving the pre-order time using DFS in a tail recursion.
How can I do the same for the post-order time (functionally and tail recursive)?

Comment: What is your specific problem? Why can you do something in pre-order but can't in post-order? Please write your working code for pre-order.

Comment: Just in case, [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)